# How to get other column values in ORACLE trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger on delete on particular table as shown below. When the trigger is executed it seems like only providing the values of the column which are modified using `old.columnName`. How can I get the values of other columns so that I can insert all the needed column values in another table?

Below is the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUDIT_TRIGGER 
  AFTER DELETE ON TABLE_T2
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
    FILE_HANDLER UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

BEGIN
    FILE_HANDLER := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('Test_Dir','trigger_log_file_delete.txt','w');
    UTL_FILE.PUT(FILE_HANDLER, '----START LOG---- '||+CHR(10));
    UTL_FILE.PUT(FILE_HANDLER,to_char(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MI:SSAM')||+CHR(10));
    UTL_FILE.PUT(FILE_HANDLER, ':OLD.OBJECT_ID = '||:OLD.OBJECT_ID||+CHR(10));
    UTL_FILE.PUT(FILE_HANDLER, ':OLD.PRIMARY_KEY = '||:OLD.PRIMARY_KEY||+CHR(10));
    UTL_FILE.PUT(FILE_HANDLER, '----END LOG---- '||+CHR(10));
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(FILE_HANDLER);
END;
```

Below is the content of the file to which I am printing:

```
----START LOG---- 
2017/11/23:08:27:49PM
:OLD.OBJECT_ID = 
:OLD.PRIMARY_KEY = 46
----END LOG----
```

Here in the output, I cant get the `OBJECT_ID` although I am getting the `PRIMARY_KEY` of the deleted row. I know that `OBJECT_ID` has value in it. Please let me know how can I get the values of the other columns.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem like normal behaviour, and I can't replicate on 11.2.0.4. Deleting a row that has both columns set, I see both values in the file, Are you sure something else isn't blanking the `object_id` before the delete happens?

Comment: I am not sure about that. The delete is actually done by web app. Tried with BEFORE DELETE also. Mine Oracle version is 11.2.0.1.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, what you're doing should work. Maybe add the table DDL just in case there's anything odd, but I can't think of anything that might behave like this. It could be a bug in 11.2.0.1 of course; quick search of MoS didn't throw up anything obvious. (Bug 8587581 looked promising but you can't be setting new values on any other triggers; might be worth checking if you have others defined already though). Good luck...

Comment: Writing a log **file** from a trigger is a bad idea. What happens if the user issues a `ROLLBACK` after deleting rows? The log file will show an entry but data stays in table. Consider to insert log entries into a separate logging table.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ..  I am writing to file just for debugging, eventually I am going to insert into another table as said in the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole .. thanks for your inputs ..